# How to log name of class method and arguments it was called with in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, trace

I have used serilaization to log the objects being passed as arguments to some methods, how ever trying to do this by hand and every method in my project or even a dedicated test project for just this purpose seems excessive,

What frameworks/tools/coding methodologies can be used to log name of class method and arguments it was called with in .Net for methods only within my application?

or something that allows visualization of execution e.g.

Class A.MethodB called with obj = ObjectA , name = "abc"
   Class X.MethodZ called with obj = ObjectY , age = 34
     ....
Class A.MethodB returned ObjectZ
.
.
.

Or some way of later reconstructing the execution steps without having to explicitly coding Logging into the application

Comment: Voting to close because asking for recommendations is off-limits here on SO. I've never done it, but I hear that postsharp has an interesting take on this: https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging

Comment: probably search term you are looking for in this off-topic question is "*profiler*"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : Thank you, will use "profiler" for search, I don't get how is this off topic!

Comment: @spender : Thank you for that link, where this question would have been in the right place? Or how could I have asked for it to get links like you gave?

Comment: If you just need a quick view you could try "Call Hierarchy" view in Visual Studio.

Comment: A simple change of wording would go a long way to improving this question. Rather than asking for a recommended framework, just explain what your problem is, why your current approach to solving the problem is failing, and ask what steps you might take next to acquire more meaningful debugging information.

Comment: @Filburt : As others suggested, it seems what I am after is called Profiling, Logging or Tracing.

Comment: You can do it using Aspect Oriented Programming (essentially: postsharp simplifies this for you). I had once coded a tool that reads a DLL, wraps every function with a logging aspect and then wrote the DLL back. I don't have the code handy and it needed some IL editing, but it was worth it.

Comment: @Joe : That sounds like some code injction, yes that sounds fantastic and the preferred way for me too

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.5 you can decorate a default parameter of a method with the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute which has the name of the calling method. You can use `[CallerFilePath]` attribute to get the calling class.

```
public void Foo([CallerMemberName] string callingMethodName = null, [CallerFilePath] string callingClassName = null)
{
    // Calling Method Name
    Console.WriteLine(callingMethodName);

    // Calling Class Name
    Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(callingClassName);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(n)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return the stack frame at offset n (0 for the current method, 1 for the calling method, 2 for the caller's calling method, etc.) using reflection.

[`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(n).GetFrame(0).GetMethod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return a `MethodInfo` instance of the method calling the specified stack frame. From this you can get the method name, return type, and parameters.

Comment: I don't think this gives you the arguments, though.